# Suppress character substitution in xetex

Tags: xetex, fontspec, libertine

I have a situation where I need to place a combining ring above (U+030A) the character 'j'. Yes, it is silly, because the ring would collide with the dot above the 'j', but I want to combine them precisely to emphasize that silliness.

The font I am using, however, Linux Libertine, is being very helpful and automatically substitutes the 'j' with a dotless 'ȷ' (U+0237) if I try to put a ring above it. So the question is, how can I suppress that character substitution (not for the whole document, but just for the relevant text)? Presumably with a `\addfontfeatures{}` command?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
jj\char"030A
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dotless j replacement here is done with `ccmp` feature<sup>1</sup>, so you just need to disable that feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\sillylibertine[RawFeature={-ccmp}]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
jj\char"030A{\sillylibertine j\char"030A}
\end{document}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> How did I know? By inspecting the font in FontForge.

Comment: I did it like this: ``{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={-ccmp}}[j\char"030A]}``.

Comment: @Sverre: I generally try to avoid `\addfontfeature` unless absolutely necessary, because the way it is currently implemented is a very inefficient hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the non combining version U+02DA RING ABOVE and manually place it over the “j”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
jj\char"030A

j\vbox{
  \offinterlineskip
  \halign{%
    #\cr\hidewidth\char"02DA \hidewidth\cr\noalign{\kern-1.3ex}j\cr
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

After seeing Khaled's version, here's how to emulate it without defining a new font family.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
jj\char"030A

j\vbox{
  \offinterlineskip
  \halign{%
    #\cr\hidewidth\kern-.1em\char"02DA \hidewidth\cr\noalign{\kern-1.55ex}j\cr
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]